# D3.js network graph

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Hi I have this nice network graph going. The node that says "scanner" I am trying to make that radius bigger than the other nodes and I want the scanner to be printed on the node while the other nodes have the hover feature. I am struggling since the nodes have to be linked together in order for it to work cohesively. Thank you in advance, looking forward to how you tackle this issue.

```js
var graph = {
"nodes":[
{"name":" Scanner","group":1},
{"name":"Chemical 1 ","group":1},
{"name":"Chemical 2","group":1},
{"name":"Chemical 3","group":1},
{"name":"Chemical 4","group":1}
],
"links":[
{"source":0,"target":1,"value":1},
{"source":0,"target":2,"value":1},
{"source":0,"target":3,"value":1},
{"source":0,"target":4,"value":1},
{"source":0,"target":0,"value":1}
]
};
var width = 1000,
    height = 1000;

 

var force = d3.layout.force()
.charge(-300)
.linkDistance(300)
.size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

var drawGraph = function(graph) {
force
  .nodes(graph.nodes)
  .links(graph.links)
  .start();

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
  .data(graph.links)
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

var gnodes = svg.selectAll('g.gnode')
 .data(graph.nodes)
 .enter()
 .append('g')
 .classed('gnode', true);

var node = gnodes.append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("r", 25)
  
 
.on("mouseover", function(d)
 {
     d3.select(labels[0][d.index]).style("visibility","visible")
 })
.on("mouseout", function(d)
 {
     d3.select(labels[0][d.index]).style("visibility","hidden")
 })
 .call(force.drag);

 var labels = gnodes.append("text")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .style("visibility", "hidden");


 force.on("tick", function() {
 link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

 gnodes.attr("transform", function(d) { 
    return 'translate(' + [d.x, d.y] + ')'; 
}); 
});
};

drawGraph(graph);
```

```css
.node {
stroke: #fff;
stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.nodeDetail {
stroke: #fff;
stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
stroke: #999;
stroke-opacity: .6;
}

 .text {
font: 12px sans-serif;
pointer-events: none; }

.node {
stroke:#fff;
stroke-width:3px;
fill:#2E8B57;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Larger radius for "scanner" circle

d3.js [`selection.attr`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md#attr) accepts a function as the second parameter, allowing to set different values according to the data.

In this function, you should check whether `d.name` is "Scanner", and return a radius value accordingly.

```
.attr("r", function(d) { return d.name === 'Scanner'? 40 : 25; })
```

### Always display the label for Scanner

Similarly, `selection.style` setting visibility for labels should be initialized in a function checking data value:

```
.style("visibility", function(d) { return d.name === 'Scanner'? 'visible' : 'hidden'; });
```

In order to have the `mouseover` and `mouseout` event listeners only applying to the other nodes, use [`selection.filter`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md#filter):

```
.filter(function(d) { return d.name !== 'Scanner'})
.on("mouseover", function(d)
// ...
```

### Demo

The snippet below illustrates the solution.

Remark: The leading space character scanner node found in the question has been removed in this demo : `"Scanner"` instead of `" Scanner"`

```js
var graph = {
"nodes":[
{"name":"Scanner","group":1},
{"name":"Chemical 1 ","group":1},
{"name":"Chemical 2","group":1},
{"name":"Chemical 3","group":1},
{"name":"Chemical 4","group":1}
],
"links":[
{"source":0,"target":1,"value":1},
{"source":0,"target":2,"value":1},
{"source":0,"target":3,"value":1},
{"source":0,"target":4,"value":1},
{"source":0,"target":0,"value":1}
]
};
var width = 1000,
    height = 1000;


var force = d3.layout.force()
.charge(-300)
.linkDistance(300)
.size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

var drawGraph = function(graph) {
force
  .nodes(graph.nodes)
  .links(graph.links)
  .start();

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
  .data(graph.links)
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

var gnodes = svg.selectAll('g.gnode')
 .data(graph.nodes)
 .enter()
 .append('g')
 .classed('gnode', true);

var node = gnodes.append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("r", function(d) { return d.name === 'Scanner'? 40 : 25; })
  .call(force.drag)
  .filter(function(d) { return d.name !== 'Scanner'})
  .on("mouseover", function(d)
 {
     d3.select(labels[0][d.index]).style("visibility","visible")
 })
   .on("mouseout", function(d)
 {
     d3.select(labels[0][d.index]).style("visibility","hidden")
 })


 var labels = gnodes.append("text")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .style("visibility", function(d) { return d.name === 'Scanner'? 'visible' : 'hidden'; });


 force.on("tick", function() {
 link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

 gnodes.attr("transform", function(d) { 
    return 'translate(' + [d.x, d.y] + ')'; 
}); 
});
};

drawGraph(graph);
```

```css
.node {
stroke: #fff;
stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.nodeDetail {
stroke: #fff;
stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
stroke: #999;
stroke-opacity: .6;
}

 .text {
font: 12px sans-serif;
pointer-events: none; }

.node {
stroke:#fff;
stroke-width:3px;
fill:#2E8B57;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```